# Python2 version set to Python3 in version check

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, homebrew

So I was trying to install OpenCV in on the MacOS following this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

In step 3 the versions of python should be python 2.x checked with `python --version` and python 3.y checked with `python3 --version`. However on both commands I am getting `Python 3.6.4`. How can I fix this? I have tried to install python 2 again with `brew install python@2` and the output is `python@2 2.7.14_1 is already installed`. `which python` shows `/usr/local/bin/python` whereas `which python3` shows `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: You don't appear to have Python 2 installed. In your case both `python` and `python3` appear to run the same Python installation.

Comment: You can be absolutely certain they are the same if `python -m site` and `python3 -m site` produce the same output.

Comment: In other words, it is not a given that `python` invokes a Python 2 binary. That's just a convention, dependent on how Python was installed on your OS.

Comment: Check the edit please. Python2 seems to be installed.

Comment: But that doesn't mean it is on your path. `which python` will show you what is being executed.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: `brew info python@2` tells me: *This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/bin.* under caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Python 2 and Python 3 with Homebrew, then the Python 2 binary is named `python2`, but will not be linked into `/usr/local` unless you use `brew link` with the `--force` flag.

See `brew info python@2`:

```
$ brew info python@2 | grep Caveats -A 4
==> Caveats
This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin
If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your PATH then add
the following to ~/.bash_profile:
  export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@2/libexec/bin:$PATH"

$ brew info python@2 | grep 'not symlinked' -A 2
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
```

You can run

```
/usr/local/opt/python\@2/bin/python2
```

if you need to run it directly, or you can force homebrew to link it in anyway with:

```
brew link --force python@2
```

at which point `/usr/local/bin/python2` will be added.

The tutorial is rather outdated; how homebrew handles Python has changed. Just use `python2` wherever it uses `python`.

To further address the tutorial:

- `brew linkapps` is deprecated
- the `homebrew/science` tap is deprecated, the formulas in that tap have been migrated, `opencv3` can be installed without additional taps.
- the current version of the `opencv3` natively supports both Python 2 and 3, no configuration switches required
- the formula directly depends on the Python 2 and 3 formulae, installing `opencv3` will automatically install Python.

So just run `brew install opencv3`, follow any additional instructions that command prints (could be none).

Do make sure you update Homebrew as there were some dependencies missing (see [my bug report with Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/24924)). If you don't, you'll have to run `brew install hdf5 tesseract` to install dependencies that should have been optional.

The tutorial is almost entirely obsolete now.

Comment: @Rodrigues: I can't help you unless you are being more specific. What does `/usr/local/bin/python2 -V` produce?

Comment: that returns `-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Rodrigues: ah, I needed to upgrade to the newest kegs. `python2` is no longer installed into the default location. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am thankful for your effort but that still doesn't address the issue of the question. To install openCV as in the tutorial `python --version` has to return some python2 version. After doing what you recommended I still get a python3 version for `python --version`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Rodrigues you’ll have to use `python2` everywhere you need Python 2. The tutorial hasn’t accounted for that possibility, but just use `python2` and move on.

Comment: @Rodrigues: I just looked more closely at the tutorial. It is outdated, all you need is `brew install opencv3` and you are done.

Comment: Again, thank you for the help, but it didn't work.

After I did just `brew install opencv3` I tried importing to pyhton with `import cv3` and `import cv2`. Both output an error. The error to import cv2 is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.101.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_1/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: @martjin I found a workaround and the version check of python and python3 are now both alright, and I managed to import cv2 to the python shell. However the atom editor won't recognize import cv2, and it also can't import matplotlib. The error message to import cv2 is `import cv2
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.101.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_1/lib/libopencv_hdf.3.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: @Rodrigues: hrm. the HDF library issue may well be a bug in the formula, the `hdf5` dependency is missing in that case. As for atom, I'm **guessing** that you need to configure atom to use the correct Python binary. Not familiar enough with Atom to tell you how, however.

Comment: @Rodrigues: I filed a bug report to address the missing dependencies, and updated my answer with a work-around for now.